# Python: test response stream with md5 checksum

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest

I am just getting started with Python and I would like to test the repose of my application by doing an md5sum of the response which is essentially a binary file stream.

test_file.py

```
import main
import unittest
import hashlib

class MainTest(unittest.TestCase):

  def setUp(self):
    self.app = main.app.test_client()
...
  # This test checks if the app retuns our new firmware correctly
  def test_get_firmware_esp_new(self):
    rv = self.app.get('/firmware',
              environ_base={'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'test-blabla'})
    print rv.response.__dict__
    self.assertEqual(hashlib.md5(rv.response).hexdigest(), 'bf8ad256d69fa98b9facca6fb43cb234')
```

The error that I get is this:

```
  File "test_file.py", line 24, in test_get_firmware_esp_new
    self.assertEqual(hashlib.md5(rv.response).hexdigest(), 'bf8ad256d69fa98b9facca6fb43cb234')
TypeError: must be convertible to a buffer, not ClosingIterator
```

In main.py I have a line which does something like this:

```
return get_stream_fw(FWupdate)
```

streamfw.py

```
from flask import Response, stream_with_context
import requests

def get_stream_fw(name):
  url = 'https://media.giphy.com/media/9Sxp3YOKKFEBi/giphy.gif'
  req = requests.get(url, stream = True)
  return Response(stream_with_context(req.iter_content(chunk_size=1024)), content_type = req.headers["content-type"])
```

What is the proper way to do a hash of the response which is actually a stream that would not exceed 1MB of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading `help(hashlib)` I think you can iterate your response something like this:

```
hs = hashlib.md5()
...
for i in rv.response:
  hs.update(i)

self.assertEqual(hs.hexdigest(), ...)
```

Comment: This produces a MD5 checksum but it is not the same as the file that should get downloaded.

Comment: rv.response.__dict__ is
.{'_next': <functools.partial object at 0x7f17aafa6b50>, '_callbacks': [<built-in method close of generator object at 0x7f17aafd8be0>, <bound method Response.close of <Response streamed [200 OK]>>]}
perhaps only part of it should be check-summed.

Comment: Try iterating over the response and printing. You may need to skip the headers.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: This is the test file: https://github.com/bogdanr/OTA/blob/master/test_initial.py

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing it like this:

```
hs = hashlib.md5()
hs.update(rv.data)
self.assertEqual(hs.hexdigest(), '80c9574fc2d169fe9c097239c2ed0b02')
```

so instead of using `rv.response` I used `rv.data`